# A texture that repeats on the left and another that repeats on the right

Tags: html, css, background-image, repeat

I don't know how to do this, but I would like to have 2 repeating textures, one that repeats to the left and one to the right.

instead of:

```
#header {
   background-image : Url('My_Two_Textures_Combined.png');
   background-repeat : repeat-x; /*Which repeats my joined textures a long the x axis*/
}
```

I would like:

```
#header {
   background-image : Url('My_Left_Texture');
   background-repeat : repeat-x-left; /*Which would ideally repeat my texture to the left on the x axis*/
   background-image : Url('My_Right_Texture');
   background-repeat : repeat-x-Right; /*Which would ideally repeat my texture to the right on the x axis*/
}
```

I hope there's a way to do this because I think it would look nice on my website. I will try to look at other ways to do this, like with pseudo commands or something. If I find anything I will post it here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css selectors like `:before` and `:after`, and place one of your backgrounds in `#header:before {}` and one in `#header:after {}`.

Comment: So what you mean is, I could have one repeat one the x, and then one repeat on the x, but after the first one has repeated? But then I'll only have one texture. The one that gets rendered last, right?

Comment: Do you at least had the curiosity to google what :before and :after means?

Comment: I'm sorry I asked such an easy question.

Comment: Your'e right it seems I could just use pseudo commands. I'll make sure to mark this question right in 6 mins, for other people who would like to know this.

Comment: I'll google it next time :) I know you're not fools, i'm sorry if you got offended by that, I meant no offense, Thank you so much Caelea! you've been great help! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy your stay here and help will come anytime.

Comment: I'm going to mark this one right because it works and because it was the first one. Thank you everyone for the very kind help! the very best to you all :) have a Cheers! from mithos :)

Comment: Pseudo selectors [don't have great support](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/) in older browsers. Particularly IE7,

Comment: @flem we're in 2012 so for IE7 you can and should use Google Chrome Frame.

Comment: @Caelea. A plugin is not a suitable alternative to progressive enhancement. What if the end user does not have sufficient rights to install plugins?

Comment: @flem you don't need administrator rights for that, it will work without them. But that's another discussion

Answer (score 6):

:before and :after is a good solution, but you can always take a look at multiple backgrounds with CSS3. Obviously, support is also a little limited: > IE8, but this would do the trick too.

```
background-image: url(left.png), url(right.png);
background-position: left bottom, right bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Nice use of CSS3! I myself didn't know CSS3 supported multiple backgrounds. Cool.

Comment: Hi Carl! I like the sound of that, will try :) Cheers!

Comment: Hey Carl yours works too! But how do I mark 2 questions right?

Comment: Great! You can't, as far as I know, just mark whichever method you prefer as a correct answer.

Comment: @MithosAnnar. You can change the correct answer if you think another is more appropriate. Mark correct the one that you feel best answers the question. Remember that future visitors don't care who answered first. They want the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Compose your header of two divs side by side. Each with its own texture.

Comment: exactly what I was thinking :).

Comment: +1.  `:before` and `:after` will work nicely, but I like the simplicity of using 2 divs.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd do, but it's bit clumsy, isn't it? The CSS3 solution is very neat.

Comment: Hi flem, How does that repeat?

Comment: @MithosAnnar. Just enabled repeat-x.

Comment: @BeetleTheNeato. The CSS3 solution is neat but it would require graceful degradation. My suggested method should work in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/9V2vE/9/ (replace the background-color with an image)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! thats definitely on the right track! I just need them to repeat :)

Comment: if it helped you please press the checkbox if you want too :p. well you should replace the "background-color" with:
background-image:url("path/of/image/image.png");
background-repeat:repeat-x; //repeat-y; //repeat;

glad I could help :)