# Set two images for left and right borders for an HTML form

Tags: html, image, css

I have an HTML form. I have two images; one in which a blurred shade goes towards the left and another in which the shade goes towards the right. Now, I want to use these two images as the border images for the left and right sides of a form respectively.

Is it possible to achieve this via HTML/CSS?

Comment: can you give me the code and that images.

Comment: See this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711776/a-texture-that-repeats-on-the-left-and-another-that-repeats-on-the-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the [CSS3 shadow instead](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/)?

you can customize it in many ways. Maybe it suits your needs and it seems like a cleaner way to add shadows than to have the visitor downloading images.